# Inserting an array into Excel

Tags: java, arrays, excel, jxl, jexcelapi

I have an array that I want to retrieve the values from and insert them into excel using Jxl, one value into one row eg:

```
1| blah blah blah

2| blah blah blah

3| blah blah blah
```

I can retrieve the values from the array as is shown in the code below, but inserting them into rows is proving difficult for me....the best I have managed through various attempts is inserting the right number of rows but all of the same value (the last value stored in the array).

```
private static void InsertStrings() throws RowsExceededException, WriteException {
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting Write to Excel");
        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Documents\\Development\\Seaport Crawler\\CrawlerResults.xls"));

        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Results", 0);
        Label label = new Label(0, 0, "Notices to Mariners"); 
        sheet.addCell(label);
        for ( int indx = 0; indx < arr_Heading.size(); indx++)
        {
            /********HEADING and TITLE ARRAY*********/
            String heading;
            int rowValue = indx;            
            heading = arr_Heading.get(rowValue);    

            //Editing the Descriptions
            if (heading.contains("-")) {
                // Split it
                String string = heading;
                String[] parts = string.split("-",2);
                String part1 = parts[0]; // Heading
                String part2 = parts[1]; // Title
                //String part1s = part1.replaceAll("\\s+","");//Replace Spaces with none
                // String part2s = part2.replaceAll("\\s+","");

                System.out.println("row Value........" + rowValue + " Heading... " + part1 + " Title... " + part2);

                //Insert Strings to Excel Workbook
                Label ntmHeading = new Label(2, indx, part1);
                sheet.addCell(ntmHeading);

            }else{
                //something
            }
            // All sheets and cells added. Now write out the workbook 
            workbook.write(); 
            workbook.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("WRITE TO EXCEL FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheels. Just use Apache's POI library to manipulate spread sheets. http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Comment: @Mohammad Using JExcelApi is not reinventing the wheel. It is another library for writing Excel like POI. Which is _better_ is another discussion, but JExcelApi is definitely an available option.

Comment: I think jxl is certainly good enough for what I want to do, I think my problem is more to do with my lack of knowledge than the library....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the following statements outside the for loop:

```
workbook.write();
workbook.close();
```

Do some adjustments for try catch block/throws and it works.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, I had figured this out about a day after I had asked the question. What was happening was that because the workbook.write(); was inside of the loop it was generating a new excel sheet on each loop. this was why I was just getting the last result from the array. Once I placed it outside of the loop it worked. Anyway thanks for your time to answer and you are correct so I will accept.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. This is my first contribution to stackoverflow!.